# How to do right rest api update?

Tags: api, rest, resources, put

I am developing rest api update method for user profile resource user/profile. I am disappointed what http method should i use. Update contains some required attributes so it more PUT request, where client need to fill all attributes. But how it can extend attributes in future. If i will decide to add new attribute then it will automatically clear because client is not implement it yet.
But what if this new attribute has default value or is set by another route?
Can i use PUT with not stricting number of attributes and use old data if new isn't come in request. Or how it can be done normally?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is an application whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network -- [Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

PUT is the appropriate method to use when "saving" a new version of a document onto a web server.

> how it can extend attributes in future.

You design your schemas to be forward and backward compatible; in practice, what this means is that you can add new optional elements with reasonable default values.  When you need to add a new required element, you change the name of the schema.

You'll find prior art in this topic by searching XML literature for [must ignore](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html).

Comment: I didn't understand, what is the right method to do this. If the PUT is right, so optional properties will not may apear in request body, so that isn't right for PUT as how i understood. And what do you mean in 'change the name of the schema' if property will required? Finally i have the same question: what is the right method to do such backward compatibility update?

Comment: If the PUT is right, so optional properties will not may apear in request body, so that mean for PUT that they must be null as i understood from many articles.

Answer (score 0):

You understand correctly: PUT is for complete replacement, so values that you don't include would be lost.

Instead, use the PATCH method, which is for making partial updates. You can update only the properties you include values for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This topic is no fully covered. I think of PATCH too, but i have some required attributes and basically i need to update many attributes by one form. Does it mean that i can use POST so behavior will be like PUT but with partial of PATCH?